# How can I successfully authorize and redirect user in application using Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, api, authorization, spotify, auth0

I'm currently working on an application that utilizes the Spotify API. I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why the authorization flow isn't working. Keep getting a POST error, assuming it's in regards to my getting an authorization token. So far, we have used Auth0 with the Spotify integration. The post error doesn't occur until the user has logged in. Does anyone have experience with working with this API? Doesn't seem like the documentation is as up to date.

Initially had the POST method in our front end, calling to the

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

base URL. I've double checked our Redirect URI's, Client ID and Client secret. I have an inkling it has something to do with the way our config object is written.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think, that the documentation is outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/) and I couldn't understand which authorization flow you use. It's not enough just make a post request with an API token.

Choose the flow according to your needs and send the proper request. For instance, if you choose **Client Credentials Flow** you have to send `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `grant_type`: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/.
In this case, you'll have to handle the API response on the server side. If you need to do all the stuff on the frontend side I guess the [**Implicit Grant Flow**](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/implicit-grant/) will be a better choice. But still, you'll have to send `client_id`, `response_type`, `redirect_uri`, `state`, and `scope`.

Comment: We are using the authorization code flow. In the diagram listed in the documentation, I believe I am at step two. The post request is sending all of the required parameters to the API-- client id, client secret, grant type, code, and the redirect uri. Apologies, I thought I had included a photo with the original post-- you should be able to see the code block now.